# How to Authenticate to Facebook as Page over XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, facebook-chat

I use XMPPFramework on ios.
I can authenticate to Facebook as user with X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM, using User Id and User Access Token.
But I can't authenticate as a Page, using PageId and Page Access Token.

I receive this message about authentication failure:

```
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```